# How to get row id from sqlite using array adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to get the row id of customer record in sqlite from listview like

```
myCustomers.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //long cid = adapter.getItemId(position);
            Log.d("Customer id",String.valueOf(id));

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Services.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("CustomerID",String.valueOf(id));
            myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getBaseContext().startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
```

**even if I use long cid=adapter.getItemId(position) I dont get the id of customer but the position**

How to get the actual id using array adapter?

Comment: can you share you full activity or fragment code